# Upgrading to ufw on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: firewall, ubuntu, iptables, ufw

I've recently upgrade my Ubuntu server install to 9.04.  I'd like to install and use ufw.  Is there a way to import my existing iptables into ufw?  I'm worried about switching it on, and having all my ports closed.  I'd like to open up a single additional tcp port, but don't want to go through the complicated process of changing my iptable rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually put your old rules in "/etc/ufw/before.rules" or "after.rules".  These are in standard iptables format. There is also var/lib/user.rules, but these are overwritten by adding rules via ufw. Put your existing rules in place, add your new rules via ufw allow, and enable ufw afterwards.

Comment: I haven't configured iptables in over a year, so I don't want to relearn the process just to open a tcp port.  This is exactly what I need to get going with ufw.

Answer (score 1):

ufw is an intuitive frontend to iptables for newbies.

If you already grok iptables, I see no reason why you should switch.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can keep your iptables rules and do something like this:

1. open a screen window
2. sudo ufw enable && sleep 120 && sudo ufw disable (be sure it wont ask you passwd :D)
3. do you testing and in a worst case scenario wait 120 secs

With this method you can test certain rules, without having an issue when you have to go to the co-loc.